# Trying to integrate leaflet's movingmarker plugin to react-leaflet , i have no idea on how to do that .is there any other way to animate

Tags: leaflet, react-leaflet, leaflet.draw, react-leaflet-v3

[image]

[image]

These are my code
suggest me if there is an alternate way to animate my marker
https://ewoken.github.io/Leaflet.MovingMarker/

Answer (score 0):

I've tried several plugins to create animated markers, you can use plugin Leaflet.Motion, I think [Leaflet.Motion](https://github.com/Igor-Vladyka/leaflet.motion) has complete features, you can try it, i have make an example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/example-animate-moving-marker-using-leaflet-motion-8emis8)